# JS How to get matching id between 2 array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How do I get 2 matching id between 2 array object using javascript?

```
// Array 1
const array1 = [
  {id: 1, name: 'milla'},
  {id: 2, name: 'alice'}
]

// Array 2
const array2 = [
  {id: 3, name: 'bobba', height: '170cm', age: 22},
  {id: 2, name: 'alice', height: '169cm', age: 21},
  {id: 1, name: 'milla', height: '171cm', age: 24},
  {id: 4, name: 'ricky', height: '168cm', age: 32},
]
```

the expected output is to returned array of object of Array2 that mached with id's on array1

```
// expected result
[
  {id: 2, name: 'alice', height: '169cm', age: 21},
  {id: 1, name: 'milla', height: '171cm', age: 24},
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter and look if the same `id` exists.

```js
const
    array1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'milla' }, { id: 2, name: 'alice' }],
    array2 = [{ id: 3, name: 'bobba', height: '170cm', age: 22 }, { id: 2, name: 'alice', height: '169cm', age: 21 }, { id: 1, name: 'milla', height: '171cm', age: 24 }, { id: 4, name: 'ricky', height: '168cm', age: 32 }],
    hash = array1.reduce((r, { id }) => (r[id] = true, r), {}),
    filtered = array2.filter(({ id }) => hash[id]);

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to do this is to generate a map of the IDs in `array1` and then filter `array2` against those IDs, like so:

```js
let array1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'milla' }, { id: 2, name: 'alice' }];
let array2 = [{ id: 3, name: 'bobba', height: '170cm', age: 22 }, { id: 2, name: 'alice', height: '169cm', age: 21 }, { id: 1, name: 'milla', height: '171cm', age: 24 }, { id: 4, name: 'ricky', height: '168cm', age: 32 }];

let idMap = array1.reduce((res, curr) => (res[curr.id] = true, res), {});
let filtered = array2.filter((item) => idMap[item.id]);

console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, this is basic JS, but anyway, here's the solution:

```js
const array1 = [
  {id: 1, name: 'milla'},
  {id: 2, name: 'alice'}
]

// Array 2
const array2 = [
  {id: 3, name: 'bobba', height: '170cm', age: 22},
  {id: 2, name: 'alice', height: '169cm', age: 21},
  {id: 1, name: 'milla', height: '171cm', age: 24},
  {id: 4, name: 'ricky', height: '168cm', age: 32},
]

const map = array1.reduce((a, c) => ({ ...a, [c.id]: true }), {});
const array3 = array2.filter(item => map[item.id]);

console.log(array3);
```

Comment: This is O(n*m), you can do this in O(n) if you generate a list of IDs in a map first.